# retrieve data from Db browser using Sqllite for a bar chart

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, charts, bar-chart

I just inserted my data using java  as a combo box successfully as a text value in eclipse using mysql(DBbrowser), so what am need is  just need to get those values to the bar chart I mean there is only two values in the comboBox so those two values should be changeable how many times user enter those values . The bar chart shows the values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urVFG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HdO8.png)

Comment: Bro please add some codes so that we can understand